# How to change font and background colour of a site throughout with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I would like my users to be able to change the colour of their background and font colour using 'accessibility' buttons. The site would need to remember this as the user navigates around.

An example can be seen here:

https://www.shop4support.com/

Click the coloured letters to the left of the 'Report this page button' at the very top.

Comment: What server language are you using ? PHP ? Java ? .Net ? etc ... you could use a cookie and change the CSS file used depending on the cookie ?

Comment: Have a look at this for ideas -> http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for the dynamicdrive link ManseUK, this is the exact starting point that I needed

Comment: ive added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i know this is old - but its still applicable - and a good starting point

http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest handling this using PHP cookies, below is a sample of how you could do this:

http://pastebin.com/UeNfra7w

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for this Anon, I have found that the link above from ManseUK is a perfect starting point for me

Answer (score 1):

looks like when you click those links i just reloads the page with the defined style.

a basic example could be like this

define your styles

```
<style>
.theam_red {background:gray;color:white}
.theam_yellow {background:yellow;color:red}
</style>
```

script to change the `className`

**UPDATE**: added cookie function names, for the cookie to work im using [quirksmode cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script)

```
<script>
```

// on page load get the cookie if it exists and apply the users preffered style,
// you could also block the page/mask it untill the page is ready to apply the style, Else GET the cookie and Set the Style With your application server language eg, PHP/JSP...

```
window.onload = function (){
   if(readCookie('theam')){
      var bdy = document.getElementById('container').className = readCookie('theam');
   }
}


function setStyle(whichStyle){
var bdy = document.getElementById('container');
switch (whichStyle){

case 1: bdy.className = "theam_yellow";
createCookie('theam','theam_yellow' ,365); //cookie function cookie, name, days
break;

case 2: bdy.className = "theam_red";
createCookie('theam','theam_red' ,365); // cookie function cookie, name, days
break;
}}}
</script>
```

setting a `id` on the `body tag` for example and a default class

```
<body id="container" class="theam_default">
<input type="button" value="yellow" onclick="setStyle(1)" />
<input type="button" value="Gray" onclick="setStyle(2)" />
</body>
```

Comment: Set this up as a fiddle but it has issues, david, please visit http://jsfiddle.net/khGCX/3/

Comment: i dont know set the frame work to no (wrap head) and No-library (Pure JS)

Answer (score 0):

Read about Jquery

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: That's a bit vague isn't it? What jQuery methods help remember the user's style selection as they navigate around the site?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet without server-side session handling would be to use cookies.

Upon click on the style change button a cookie is stored with that choice client-size. You can then read that cookie on each page load to reload the user preferences.

The easiest way to do this would be using jQuery as @Kaiser says. It allows you to modify style data on page load and on clicks pretty easily.

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript solutions like http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/04/02/changing-font-size-on-a-page-with-javascript-for-better-user-experience/

Demo: http://www.vijayjoshi.org/examples/changeFont.html

Similarly you can change any other CSS styling.